# How to create a people search using Google Directory API in Apps Script/HTML Service

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-apps-script

How to create a "people search" using Google Directory API in Apps Script/HTML Service/App Engine. If i write a name in textfield it must show up all the details from Google Directory

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something internally at a company to publish data to the shared contact list.  They can then find each other through contact search in Gmail.

The textfield you're looking to put data into is called userDefinedField. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#gcUserDefinedField

Comment: It would be nice if you share a piece of code for a better insight.I tried the example but when i run , it says authorization header missing .Please assist